# VBA specialcell method of range object failed

Tags: excel, vba

I've set up a two-dimensional array, and I want to count the number of filled cells in column H for each trial in each block. I then want to print the number of filled cells next to the last row of data for each trial, into column T.

The problem I'm getting is that when I try to run the macro, Excel stops responding, and after restarting, I get the error message in the title.

Here is the code:

```
Sub dotcountanalysis2()
' create multidimensional array
Dim Participant() As Variant

Participant = Worksheets("full test").Range("A7", Range("S:S")).Value

Dim Block As Variant
Block = Columns(2)

Dim Trial As Variant
Trial = Columns(3)

' define column H as boolean variable

Dim Pressed As Boolean
Pressed = True

' begin analysis after practice trials
For Each Block In Participant
    For Each Trial In Participant
    pressedcount = Range("H:H").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
        If Cells(, 8) = Pressed Then
        Range("T:T").Value = pressedcount
        End If
    Next Trial
Next Block

End Sub
```

The error is on line:

```
pressedcount = Range("H:H").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

I'm also not sure that my syntax is correct to make it count for each trial, as I have tried stepping into the code, and it gives the total number of filled cells in column H (562), and prints it in every cell in column T. I think it's also going way past the 7011 rows of data I have, to the maximum possible number of rows.

[Here is a sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anayl.png)

Comment: Hey, can you pleas attach the file unless it contain any type of personal/confidential data?

Comment: "after restarting, I get the error message in the title" does that mean that after restarting and running the macro again you get the error? Will there be any constants in column H or will they be reset after restarting (without saving)?

Comment: @salih0vicX I'm not sure how to attach the whole file.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct when I reopen the macro file, the error message pops up immediately, I don't need to rerun the code. Nothing changes in column H, just column T, where the count is printed.

Comment: It freezes because of your range setup. As you noted above already, it runs for entire spreadsheet (million+ of rows) ... Anyway, @shecodes Maybe you could use something like http://www.filedropper.com and give us link here

Comment: @salih0vicX here you go: http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest

Comment: You are trying to run 396923697627136 iterations and you are not even using the current value in each iteration. You need to redo the loop part. Calculate `pressedcount` before the loop and then loop through the rows. If you want to use an array, take an array of column H until the end of the used range and tun through it to find the `Pressed` values. You need to use an index variable because you won't be able to get the current position in a `For Each` loop to write to the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most relevant problem is probably the fact that you create a huge variant array of values and then loop two times through it's values.

The `Participant` array contains 1048576*19 = 19922944 values. (assuming 1048576 rows in your sheet)

Now you loop through these values and for every value you loop through each value again, giving you 19922944*19922944 = 396923697627136 iterations. So that's why excel doesn't respond.

However, within each iteration, you don't even use the value...?

If you want to calculate that number of `Pressed` in column H and write that number to column T, why would you load **all** values of columns A to S into the array?

Here is what I would do in VBA

```
Dim pressedCount As Long
Dim myCell As range
Dim pressedRange As range

With Worksheets("full test")
    pressedCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns("H"))
    If pressedCount = 0 Then Exit Sub 'make sure there are cells or else the next line will fail
    Set pressedRange = .Columns("H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each myCell In pressedRange.Cells 'only loop through the cells containing something
        .Cells(myCell.Row, "T").Value = pressedCount
    Next myCell
End With
```

I used the `With` block so I don't have to write the sheet before every range which you should because otherwise it assumes you mean the active sheet.
Note that this assumes that there can be no other values than "Pressed" in column H, not even a header. If there is a header, start at row 2 and use `.Range(.Cells(2, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H"))` instead of `.Columns("H")`

However this could also be achieved using a Formula like `=IF($H7="Pressed",COUNTA(H:H),"")`

Comment: well @arcadeprecinct this is the closest I've come to what I want so far, but still not quite. The reason why I set up the array was because I need to divide my data into 30 blocks of 18 trials each, and need to know the pressed count for each trial, which should only be 1-2. With your modifications, it is now printing the number in the right rows, but it's printing the total pressed count, rather than pressed per trial per block. What did you mean in your last comment about using an index variable?

Comment: Well excel has no idea what you mean with trial and block. I think you need to use a for loop (not for each) and apply my code to 18 rows at a time instead of the whole column H. The step option of the for loop might be handy plus referencing a range by its first and last cell.

Comment: Each trial takes up numerous rows of data because one row represents one event in the trial, and the number of events in a trial varies unpredictably. In module 1 of my "fulltest" file I tried setting up an array by Diming each trial and block separately and using a For Each loop. It didn't work. I guess I'd need code that says something like
'for (name of range) (insert your code here)'
and I'd have to name the range something like
'(name of range) = Cells(, 3).value = "Trial, 1"'. How does that sound?